# How to ensure border-radius is applied to the image and not its container?

Tags: html, css

If the actual image doesn't fit the container `<img>`, then the `border-radius` will be applied to the container, which means the actual image itself may not have any rounded corners.

How do I fix this?

```html
<img src={main_content.img} alt="" className="image" />
```

```css
.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 70vh;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: border-radius: 50px; try this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no issue with the code, the issue is your giving `padding: 10px;` to the image element and your giving the same amount of radius `(border-radius: 10px;)` and therefore that padding is pushing your image inside so you can't see the radius

So either

- **You must give a div as parent of img tag and give padding to that div and remove form img tag**

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px
}

.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 70vh;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src=https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg alt="" class="image" />
</div>
```

Or

- **Give higher border radius higher than the padding**

```css
.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 70vh;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<img src=https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg alt="" class="image" />
```

These are the two possible ways

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `max-height`; `max height 100%` makes the image go outside the container and also increase the border radius.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
vertical-align:middle;
```